# Can I upgrade my laptop CPU

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, upgrade

I have Lenovo Ideapad Y510 with dual core 1.6 Ghz processor, 1GB ram, 160GB HDD. I want to upgrade my current cpu with any latest one like i3, i5 or i7 to get more speed but don't know if it is possible. I don't know how to get all technical details of the pc so I have have attached a screenshot of boot screen, hope you will find all required info about my pc to answer this question.

I am a java developer so my basic need is to run eclipse and java application and application server with db like MySql very smoothly on my machine. Earlier I was using Win7 but machine was running slow so I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 but not much improvement so I thought to upgrade the cpu and memory. I need your suggestion that to which cpu I can upgrade and should I also upgrade ram.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot upgrade Dual Core series to new I3/I5/I7 series, they are newer architecture and as minimum require different socket.

1. You can change CPU on majority of laptops, because they are not soldered on motherboard. Obviously you have to stick to the right socket. In his case you can upgrade dual core 1.6 to T9900 3.06 GHz for example.

Here is the forum post where lenovo users report their luck with upgrading CPU of this laptop:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-and-Z-series/y510-CPU-Options/td-p/14857

Please buy model of CPU that they report WORKING for your laptop.

2. You don't need extra cooling system, laptop manufacturers usually put exact cooling systems in all models to cut costs obviously. It costs more to source or manufacture different cooling system than just to use 1 on all models and change only CPU/RAM/HDD specifications.
3. If you want immediate result upgrade ram first, as was suggested by other members. 1GB of ram is really little today, and ram sticks cost nothing. Though I must say that I run ubuntu server with java/mysql/apache on 2gb and intel ATOM processors and have no problem with speed. You can try mint distribution instead? it has much lighter footprint.
4. Mysql on SSD is very fast.

Comment: I dont have much idea about H/W. Will SATA 3 SSD be compatible with this machine?

Comment: @Sandy Your laptop doesn't seem to have sata interface, it uses IDE hdd as I can see from the screenshot. IDE SSD are too expensive and limited in performance.

Comment: @Sandy Here check this thread for CPU compatibility of your laptop: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-and-Z-series/y510-CPU-Options/td-p/14857

Comment: Thanks a million for the link. It say I can upgrade my CPU from T2330 to T9300. I will give it a try.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: I'm pretty sure his laptop uses SATA, it is probably just set to IDE mode in the BIOS.

Comment: @James ah yes. could be.

Comment: I'd second the ram upgrade first.  2x2GB DDR2 SoDimm's are currently ~$50-60 on Newegg; and would almost certainly give a better speed boost than the faster CPU.  Unless you can find one cheap (I only saw $300 on amazon), the T9300 is probably more expensive than it's worth.  Between that and the ram, you'd be most of the way to a new low end laptop and a core-i3 based system would smoke your upgraded laptop.

Answer (score 4):

It's very rarely feasible to upgrade a cpu in a laptop.

1. Laptop motherboard are not really constructed to be repaired nowadays. So switching cpu is *hard* (if at all possible due to socket changes)
2. A new more powerful cpu would probably need more cooling than your laptop can provide

The standard suggestion to speed up a laptop is to max out on RAM and buy a SSD

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is no, unfortunately you wont be able to put an i3/5/7 into this laptop. It appears that is an old model, and will be a different socket to that which the latest CPU's require.

My advice to you would be to invest in a new laptop. These days you can pick up a good machine with decent specs for the amount you would need to spend to upgrade those parts. This isn't a place for product recommendations so, hopefully i have pointed you in the right direction to do your own research :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally no, laptops don't use a ZIF socket for the motherboard. upgrading a cpu in a laptop is only slightly harder than in a desktop, due to the fact that it is harder to open than a desktop, and the cpu's a harder to get.
 your first problem is Socket of CPU. "I" Series CPU follow 1155 socket with 1066 or 1333 FSB but I think your devise can't to be run with this important problems. In your image you can see your 1 slot Ram with 533 Bus. your device can run with DDR2 specification and you can't use DDR3 for your Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not think that you can do this. Laptops come with their built in capacity to function the way they are designed for.

This is just like adding an ironing capacity to a table fan. This is quite different. A c2d era pentium dual core is very different from a modern core i3 or i5, both internally and in terms of its interface with the motherboard.