# Options for upgrading laptop HDD

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade

I have a Lenovo Y510 laptop which has 160GB HDD. I want to upgrade the HDD to a 1TB HDD or some large capacity SSD. There are various HDDs and SSDs available like IDE, SATA, SATA2 and SATA3 so which HDD or SSD can I upgrade to?

Comment: This sounds like a shopping question?! You will need to find out what the motherboard and maybe chipset can work with and then research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This hard drive will work fine for it](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148591) (its the same one I have) I don't recommend a full SSD as the laptop won't technically utilize how fast it is. And to be honest I have no idea what Sandro Dzneladze is talking about regarding your CD drive because your laptop is already SATA (I looked it up)

Comment: I'm talking about 2x hdd baby.

Comment: "don't recommend a full SSD as the laptop won't technically utilize how fast it is" this is not true btw.

Comment: The hard drive I linked to is a disk/ SSD hybrid. Its sufficient for anything (I have been using mine for 2 years on 4 different laptops and for a few months used it as an external) And yea a with a Pentium laptop anything more then 7200 rpm is just not worth it + 5400 is considered legacy in my books.

Comment: Hybrid SSD will only give you SSD like performance for burst program activity. While SSD will operate evenly.

Comment: So your telling me he should blow money on an SSD with a Pentium laptop. Yea that makes a bunch of sense.

Comment: He is upgrading CPU to T9X series. Why is it blowing money? if you upgrade (laptop) in the future, you keep SSD. pretty smart in my books.

Comment: I didn't see his other questions. I don't want to be in the middle of this or anything but if he doesn't have the knowledge to upgrade a hard drive or CPU who the hell is going to put the CPU in the laptop? I am just wondering. And to be honest I have never heard of anyone upgrading a laptop CPU before..those motherboards can be weird.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: I was thinking to upgarde CPU as I told in my other question but when I checked the price on ebay india I found it costs 26K. In that much of price I can buy a new laptop. Recently I bought a new Lenovo laptop for my brother in law in 25K so I have dropped idea of upgrading cpu. Now my only focus is ram and hdd. I will check if my system hdd is SATA or IDE then will upgrade it.

Comment: Its SATA. And I guess if your from india that newegg site wont help.

Comment: @Doubtme: Are you sure it is SATA? coz in my previous [question](http://superuser.com/questions/450322/can-i-upgrade-my-laptop-cpu) SandroDzneladze told me that it is IDE.

Comment: [Here is where I saw that it says SATA](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/lenovo-ideapad-y510/4507-3121_7-32815684.html). Serial ATA = SATA

Comment: Doubtme is correct, it is SATA.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use CD-ROM often?

In your shoes I would this...
Get both normal HDD and SSD, 1 for storage and the other for operating system and applications.

Upgrade your main HDD to 500GB sata II 5400 for file storage.

Get 64-128GB SATA II SSD
and also this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/SATA-2nd-HDD-Caddy-For-IBM-Lenovo-ThinkPad-T60-Series-Laptop-T60-T61-R60-R61-New-/120951006157?pt=US_Drive_Bay_Caddies&hash=item1c293de3cd

So you will get rid of CD-ROM and instead have SSD placed into hdd caddy in the emptied space.

On SSD you will load your operating system and you will use 500GB hdd for file storage.

Answer (score 0):

Let me congratulate you! Y510p is a beautiful and power packed laptop . I have it and love it to pieces :) 
Few months back I decided to upgrade from the 5400 rpm 1 TB hdd which it had.

The internal 1 tb 5400 rpm hdd of y510p has Sata 3 interface
Also it should have the newer M3 interface too.

So you have two option...

Keep the existing Sata 3 internal hdd and buy a relatively more expensive M3 compatibile ssd and plug it in.

Swap out the internal sata 3 hdd with a sata 3 Ssd ( bit cheaper) Using an hdd caddy you can choose to replace the dvd rom drive with the internal hdd inside the caddy.

I have gone with the 2nd option , Samsung Evo 850 256GB ssd model is the one i hve purchased. It roxks and works just fine with y510p :)

Cheers